# How to explain drastic jump in memory allocation latency?

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, windows-ce

Intel Celeron 847 with 8GB of RAM. (C/C++ not .NET)

This is the only thread/function running, on Windows EC7.

It just loops through allocating 1MB of memory, 1000 times.

However, after about the 122nd iteration through the loop, the time it takes to allocate jumps from around 47 microseconds to 327 microseconds.

What are some possible reasons that would explain this to my boss?

```
while ( i < ITERATIONS )
{
QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
start = double(li.QuadPart) / PCFreq;

// allocate 1MB
ptr = new char [1048576]; // 1 byte * 1048576 = 1 MB

QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
stop = double(li.QuadPart) / PCFreq;

delayAlloc[i] = stop - start;

}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Just to be sure, I executed the test 3 more times, each of the results were very similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Q: This is a physical device (and not an emulator), correct? Q: How much physical RAM is on your device?  Q: Are you coding in .Net, or C/C++? Q: Can you run a WinCE equivalent of TaskMgr or Performance Monitor?  What about [DevHealth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj584887.aspx)?  You need to get more information before you can possibly hope to answer this question...

Comment: Windows ce has a paging pool - as memory is allocated there is a limit that after which, pages are swapped out to accomodate new pages. See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2008/01/19/paging-and-the-windows-ce-paging-pool.aspx

Comment: One explanation for your boss is that you managed to create a memory leak even in this simple piece of code?

Comment: You might try using a debugger to step into the new code on the 1st and 123rd iterations to see what code path it takes.  Which compiler are you using?  That will tell us which memory allocator it is.

Comment: You're not touching the memory that is allocated: The first thing to find out is: is the memory from `new` being committed (assigned frames of physical memory?) Or is it just unpopulated virtual memory?

Comment: @kfsone: yes, but how/why?

Comment: @sam: with 8GB of RAM, why is that necessary?

Comment: @P.S. : Depending on how the allocator and Windows itself manages memory blocks (pages), there might be indirections to get new blocks, if a pretty big slab is already allocated (like @Hari Mahadevan explained). Think of this as of a container structure, the more allocation entries, the more work must be done in order to find a free gap in memory. There are also hardware limits, read about the CPU's MMU&TLB, they have a limited amount of (cache) entries and certain overhead when pulling memory pages (+entry) through caches. To get meaningful results, `memset()` the block, to 'dirty' the pages.

Comment: You have 8GB of RAM in the hardware, but what is *actually* reserved for and visible to the OS?  Look in the Control Panel _> System->Memory.  I'm certain there's an explanation, but why, exactly, does it matter anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets simplify your code and remove the timing stuff.

```
while ( i < ITERATIONS )
{
    // allocate 1MB
    ptr = new char [1048576]; // 1 byte * 1048576 = 1 MB
}
```

The system is allocating 1Mb to you and returning you the address. Then you are asking for another one, and storing the new address in the same variable you were holding the previous address.

`new` returns a pointer, and a pointer is literally *just* the address of the allocation. It's not a special electronic key, not an object with scope, it's just the numeric value of the location in memory where your allocation starts.

It is your responsibility to *tell* the allocator when you no-longer want the memory. There's no way for it to know what you do with that address data, whether you store it or not.

```
while ( i < ITERATIONS )
{
    // allocate 1MB
    ptr = new char [1048576]; // 1 byte * 1048576 = 1 MB

    delete [] ptr;
}
```

If you don't do this, the allocated memory will **never** be returned to the pool until your application terminates.

That means your application's memory footprint is growing. Under normal Windows that might not be a problem but you are running under the embedded flavor of Windows where *one* Mb of memory is already a significant amount. The first 122Mb are probably pre-reserved to your app. But once you allocate all of the heap your app started with, the allocator has to get it's heap resized to be able to provide you extra allocations, and since this is embedded Windows, the resizing is done pessimistically.

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason I can think of is that program heap is fully consumed at some stage and thereafter the memory manager has to go through hoops and jumps to manage further allocation requests by swapping some of the already allocated chunks to secondary storage. A lot would depend on how much installed RAM you have and how much of it is available for your program.

What's the behavior if you set the allocation size to 512K instead of 1MB? Does the same thing happen, but at ~200th iteration? Can you increase the available RAM and try? (I don't know what Windows EC7 is, but basing my response on my WinDesktop experience).

Comment: that is what I was also thinking but was not sure, I will try changing the size to see if it is consistent around 200 iterations...thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't using RAM at all, that doesn't happen until you actually access the arrays.  So the only work that needs to be done is to find a hole in the virtual memory address space and to *commit* it.  Finding a hole can't have a sudden jump like that.  Committing can, there's a cheap and an expensive version of that.  The cheap one is where space in the paging file is already available.  The expensive one is where it needs to be created by *growing* the paging file.

Verify this by running the program *twice*.  The second time the jump should occur later or not at all.

Comment: ok, i will run again, what leads you to believe the second time, the jump should occur later?

Comment: Humor us, run the test twice.